# The box-shadow doesn't appear at bottom of equal height divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout consisting of responsive boxes which have equal height. They have `box-shadow` but bottom shadow doesn't appear.

I think it's because `overflow:hidden` for `div#latest` which is set to make boxes equal height as it is recommended in [One True Layout Method](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/#article-header-id-3).

HTML Code:

```
    <div id="latest">
                    <div id="section-header"><h4>NEWS</h4></div>
          <div class="row">
<div id="article-container" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div id="article">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/74aBLNQ.jpg" />
                                </figure>
                                <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
                                <div id="meta" class="row">
                                    <div id="meta-category" class="col-md-9"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a></div>
                                    <div id="meta-view" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">124</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <div id="article-container" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div id="article">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/m0D77HS.jpg" />
                                </figure>
                                <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
                                <div id="meta" class="row">
                                    <div id="meta-category" class="col-md-9"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a></div>
                                    <div id="meta-view" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">124</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <div id="article-container" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div id="article">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/995osiQ.jpg" />
                                </figure>
                                <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
                                <div id="meta" class="row">
                                    <div id="meta-category" class="col-md-9"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a></div>
                                    <div id="meta-view" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">124</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <div id="article-container" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div id="article">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/JI7P0ZJ.jpg" />
                                </figure>
                                <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
                                <div id="meta" class="row">
                                    <div id="meta-category" class="col-md-9"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a></div>
                                    <div id="meta-view" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">124</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</div>
          </div>
          <div id="latest">
                    <div id="section-header"><h4>MOST READ</h4></div>
          <div class="row">
<div id="article-container" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div id="article">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/74aBLNQ.jpg" />
                                </figure>
                                <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
                                <div id="meta" class="row">
                                    <div id="meta-category" class="col-md-9"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a></div>
                                    <div id="meta-view" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">124</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <div id="article-container" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div id="article">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/m0D77HS.jpg" />
                                </figure>
                                <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
                                <div id="meta" class="row">
                                    <div id="meta-category" class="col-md-9"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a></div>
                                    <div id="meta-view" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">124</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <div id="article-container" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div id="article">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/995osiQ.jpg" />
                                </figure>
                                <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
                                <div id="meta" class="row">
                                    <div id="meta-category" class="col-md-9"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a></div>
                                    <div id="meta-view" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">124</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <div id="article-container" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div id="article">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/JI7P0ZJ.jpg" />
                                </figure>
                                <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
                                <div id="meta" class="row">
                                    <div id="meta-category" class="col-md-9"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a></div>
                                    <div id="meta-view" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">124</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</div>
          </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
  background: #ebebeb;
}
#article-container {
        padding: 1em;
}
#article {
    padding: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2) 
}
#article figure {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#article figure img {
    /*height: 30%;*/
}
#article h4 {
        padding: 1em;
}
#article h4 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
#article h4 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
}
#meta{
    color: #ccc;
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
#meta a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
}
#meta a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#latest {
    padding-left:2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#section-header {
    height: 40px;
    width:100%;
    background: #FFF;
    display:table;
    border-left: 5px #FFC640 solid;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top:2em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2)
}
#section-header h4 {
    padding-left: 1em;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell; 
}
```

Here is the screenshot showing how the problem occurs: [image]

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hkxmuxdq/1/)

**P.S.** I am using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: You should start by turning your `id`s into `class`es. An ID has to be unique, so it can only be used once per page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st of all, ID's are **unique** and you are duplicating ID's, so use classes instead.

Since you are using bootstrap, you are missing `.container` that wraps the `.row` and `col-*-*`.

Then, to have equal `height` instead of that hack, there is new flexible layout you can use, which is `flexbox` and then the `box-shadow` will show up

```css
body {
  background: #ebebeb;
}
.row {
  display: flex
}
.article-container {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex
}
.article {
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}
.article figure {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.article figure img {
  /*height: 30%;*/
}
.article h4 {
  padding: 1em;
}
.article h4 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.article h4 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.meta {
  color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.meta a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc;
}
.meta a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.section-header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  display: table;
  border-left: 5px #FFC640 solid;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}
.section-header h4 {
  padding-left: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest container">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h4>NEWS</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 article-container">
      <div class="article">
        <figure>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/74aBLNQ.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
        <div class="row meta">
          <div class="col-md-9 meta-category"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 meta-view">124</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 article-container">
      <div class="article">
        <figure>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/m0D77HS.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
        <div class="row meta">
          <div class="col-md-9 meta-category"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 meta-view">124</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 article-container">
      <div class="article">
        <figure>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/995osiQ.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
        <div class="row meta">
          <div class="col-md-9 meta-category"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 meta-view">124</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 article-container">
      <div class="article">
        <figure>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/JI7P0ZJ.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
        <div class="row meta">
          <div class=c lass="col-md-9 meta-category"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 meta-view">124</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="latest container">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h4>MOST READ</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 article-container">
      <div class="article">
        <figure>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/74aBLNQ.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
        <div class="row meta">
          <div class=c lass="col-md-9 meta-category"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 meta-view">124</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 article-container">
      <div class="article">
        <figure>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/m0D77HS.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
        <div class="row meta">
          <div class="col-md-9 meta-category"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 meta-view">124</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 article-container">
      <div class="article">
        <figure>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/995osiQ.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
        <div class="row meta">
          <div class="col-md-9 meta-category"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 meta-view">124</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 article-container">
      <div class="article">
        <figure>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/JI7P0ZJ.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <h4><a href="#">About surviving despite of everything</a></h4>
        <div class="row meta">
          <div class="col-md-9 meta-category"><a href="#">CATEGORY</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 meta-view">124</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. When I use .container, other content in the page seems problematic. When I don't, it work properly. Does it cause a problem in future?

Answer (score 0):

Well that was not because of `overflow:hidden` in `#latest`, but you added huge number of margin and padding in `article`, change as below and then set it's height and width accordingly,

```
#article {
    padding: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2) 
}
```

Comment: It's not my solution, I am trying to set equal heights for fluid boxes and it is possible with methods in the page that I referred.